# What lens adapter to pair a XiaoYi action camera with an SLR lens?

Tags: lens-adapter

I want to connect an SLR lens (standard 18-55 mm for example) to my XiaoYi action camera using some sort of adapter. However, even when I align the camera and lens perfectly, it cannot focus properly.

I think that some kind of special lens between the camera and the main lens could solve this problem, but I have no idea what kind of lens I would use.

Comment: I would be surprised if this is possible, and it sounds quite impractical as well. What do you hope to achieve from doing it ?

Comment: Lens and optic design is specific to the size of the image sensor and the distance between the optics and the image plane.  There are physical limitations which may be impossible to correct when combining different formats.  Why do you want to use a 18-55mm lens?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Related: [Installing SLR lens on incompatible devices?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43212/installing-slr-lens-on-incompatible-devices)

Comment: I have seen a phone to SLR lens adapter some time ago and I was just wondering, if it's possible with this camera as well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing SLR lens on incompatible devices?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43212/installing-slr-lens-on-incompatible-devices)

Comment: @StephenG, impractical yes. Impossible, well...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVmilrBvdAc

Comment: @inkista I've never understood the attraction of things like this - they look like a handling nightmare.  I use adapted lenses (SLR) on my MILCs, but that works because essentially they handle as intended on that set up and the balance and controls are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **[Depth of Field Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-of-field_adapter)**. It basically projects an image of the scene onto ground glass that you can record with your action camera. It is used to "convert" the depth of field and field of view of one format into another. Disadvantages include reduced light transmission and the potential to capture the texture of the focusing screen.

There are adapters that blur the texture of the focusing screen by moving it with a motor. You can also experiment with not using a focusing screen, but results will be inconsistent.

[image: DOF Adapter]